# How to run server.jar file on web server

Tags: java, jar, mmo

I'm using Web.com to host a website for my MMO. I'm currently developing a simple server and testing it out on the web server. I've uploaded the server.jar file to the web server and now I can't figure out how to run it. How would I run it on the webserver?

Also the client would need an IP address to connect to, would that IP be the server's IP? And one more thing, what port should I use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Web.com doesn't seem like the type of host you need for this. You'll need some sort of VPS-provider, such as AWS, DigitalOcean, or Linode. They'll give you a Linux virtual machine with SSH access, which is what you need to host your server.

To get SSH access after renting your server, you'll need an SSH client. On Linux and Mac, this is preinstalled - just run `ssh <ip>`. On Windows, you'll need something like Putty.

Then, you'll need to add your `server.jar` as a startup script. Linux distributions have various ways to do this, but the most common way (on recent Ubuntu versions, Arch Linux, and many other distributions) is through Systemd. Add a file like this to `/etc/systemd/system/mmoserver.service` (`nano` is a good terminal editor for newbies, run `nano <path>`):

```
[Unit]
Description=MMO Server

[Service]
ExecStart=java -jar /path/to/server.jar -options=blahblahblah

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Basically, this says when the server starts into multi-user mode (the normal mode, as opposed to single-user mode which is only when something breaks hard), it runs the `ExecStart` command - your server. Now reboot and use `ps aux` to verify your server is running. Pipe it to `less` (`ps aux | less`) to scroll using the arrow keys, use `q` to exit `less`.

You can find your VPS' external ip by running `ifconfig` and looking for `inet addr:...`. That said, you'll need the ip to SSH to it in the first place, so you'll probably already have it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can run the server using an `ssh` session with the command:

```
ssh user@server 'java -jar server.jar'
```

If clients should establish a connection with the server, the IP adress is indeed the IP adress over the server.

The port is in many cases "hardcoded" in the Java application (you need to inspect the source code), or it is given as a parameter with the `jar` (for instance `java -jar server.jar -port 8080`, other programs (like *Apache* use a set of config files where the port must be specified). (Mind this depends on the actual java program. Flags not interpreted by the program are in many cases simply ignored).

Comment: How exactly would I access ssh?

Comment: Sadly not that I know of.

Comment: @JacobPickens: I think before you can set up a server, you need to have some basic knowledge about a terminal/command line.

Comment: well yes I know how to use the command line and what not but do you mean the terminal of my Mac or the terminal of my hosted server?

Comment: Well with `ssh`, you open the "terminal" on your server. So you can execute commands there. So you open your terminal on your own machine, of you type `ssh user@server`, you start an interactive session with your server. If you type `ssh user@server 'command'`. You ask to perform the given task at server side.

Comment: alright it says that my server only allows sftp, is there a way to launch a jar from there